# Method coverage in an android application without source code

Tags: java, android, function, testing, code-coverage

Can someone give me an ide about method coverage in android apks without having the source code?
I heard that there is an android specific version of emma project that can give method coverage information through instrumentation. But if I do not have the source code how can I instrument th code?

My goal is to some how get a report on which methods were called in the runtime while running the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need emma to get a report of which methods are called.
Just:

1. start DDMS
2. selected the device
3. select the process
4. press "Start method profiling" button (arrows with red button)
5. "Stop method profiling"

and you'll get a report like this one:

[image]

See the details at http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: does this require androidmanifestfile set to debuggable to true? in this case i cannot do it as I do not have the source code.

Comment: btw this method works, though I needed to decompile the third party apps to set debuggable to true. A great thanks.Now all i need is to parse the file to get the method information.