# Appium Android code coverage w/o root or emulator?

Tags: android, jenkins, appium

I'm searching for methods to analyze code coverage for the company's Appium/JUnit automated testing.  We pick up the apk from an upstream Jenkins pipeline and deploy it to our test bed.  The big caveat is that our app won't run on a rooted environment, not an emulator.  Can I get emma to run in this type of setup?  Would it be wiser to run jacoco and have it work with the sonar reports generated upstream?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133761/jacoco-code-coverage-in-android-studio?

Comment: I'm using maven, so I'll need to look into something equivalent with Jacoco maven plugin

Comment: You can certainly give Cobertura a try.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve collocating the apk source code.  I've looked, but not found a method involving Cobertura.  Android's DDMS might be promising, based on this example ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644335/method-coverage-in-an-android-application-without-source-code